# issue rendering Django Choice field from model on template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to follow the example in the Django documentation to include a choice field to my form. I've created the following choice model:

```
class Ref_AccessDescription(models.Model):
    FACILITY = '7'
    MARKET = '6'
    DIVISION = '5'
    GROUP = '4'
    CORPORATE = '3'
    DEVELOPER = '1'
    access_level_CHOICES = (
        (FACILITY, 'Facility'),
        (MARKET, 'Market'),
        (DIVISION, 'Division'),
        (GROUP, 'Group'),
        (CORPORATE, 'Corporate'),
        (DEVELOPER, 'Developer'),
    )
    access_level = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=access_level_CHOICES,
        default=FACILITY,
    )

    def is_corporate(self):
        return self.access_level in (self.CORPORATE)

    def is_developer(self):
        return self.access_level in (self.DEVELOPER)
```

Then I create the following form pulling all objects:

```
class AccessLevelForm(forms.Form):
    accesslevel = forms.ModelChoiceField(Ref_AccessDescription.objects.all())
```

I create the view to use the form passing my arguments:

```
form = AccessLevelForm()
errors = form.errors or None # form not submitted or it has errors

args = {'retreivecheckbox': reportlist,'form': form,'errors': errors}

return render(request,'accounts/requestaccess.html', args)
```

When I try to render the form in a template, it doesn't populate it with my choice field.

```
<label for="accesslevel">Access Level</label>
<select class="form-control" id="accesslevel">
  <option>{{ form.accesslevel }} </option>
```

I've also tried to just use{{ form }}and nothing gets populated

Comment: I don't understand why you're putting the accesslevel field inside an existing select/option.

Comment: It's supposed to be a drop down option the user selects, it's part of a forloop for approver types, is that the incorrect way to do it?

Comment: But `form.accesslevel` is *already* the entire dropdown. It renders the `select` and all the `option` elements for you. You shouldn't wrap it inside another set of tags.

Comment: I wasn't aware I could call just the field in a template, this makes my life a lot easier.  Now that I remember in my reading for variables to be passed you had to create a context for them..